# React-Native styles not getting appplied

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React-Native styles are not getting applied in two screens, I already saved the changes but when it gets applie to one screen, the other one loses it's style. Here is the code :

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
const heigth = Dimensions.get('window').height
styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Container:{
        flex:1,
        width: '100%',
        width: width -20,
        height:heigth - 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    ViewContainer:{
      width: width -40,
      flex:1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    input:{
      borderBottomColor: '#F5FCFF',
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      borderRadius:30,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      paddingLeft: 8,
      width:250,
      height:45,
      marginBottom:8,
      marginTop:20,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems:'center',
      marginLeft:40
  },
    Button:{
      width:"80px",
      height:"30px",
      margin:100,
      justifyContent:'flex-end',
      alignItems: "flex-end",
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      height:65,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginBottom:20,
      width:250,
      borderRadius:30,
      marginLeft:70
    },
    Container:{
      flex:1,
      justifyContent:"flex-end",
      alignItems: "flex-end",
    },
})
```

and the other one here:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { getPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-location';
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
const heigth = Dimensions.get('window').height


styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Container:{
        flex:1,
        width: width -20,
        height:heigth-30,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    input:{
        marginTop: heigth/4,
        margin: 20,
        borderBottomColor: '#F5FCFF',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderRadius:30,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        width:250,
        height:45,
        marginBottom:20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        marginLeft:70
      
    },
    Button:{
      height:45,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom:20,
        width:250,
        borderRadius:60,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginTop:90,
        marginLeft:70
    },
    Button2:{
      flex:1,
      height:20,
      borderRadius:60,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      width:30,
      color:'#f0f8ff',
      alignSelf:'flex-end',
      borderStyle: 'dashed'
    }
})
```

I'm using stack navigation and think that it migth be the problem, here is the code:
function Tabnav() {

```
  return(
   <Tab.Navigator 
   screenOptions={{
    tabBarActiveTintColor: '#101010',
    TabBarLabelStyle: {
      fontSize: 15,
    },
    TabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffd700',
    
    }
  }}
 >
     <Tab.Screen name="Homescreen" component={Home} 
     options={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-home" color={color} size={size} />
      )
    }}/>

     <Tab.Screen name="Perfil" component={userProfile}
     options={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={size} color={color} />
      )
    }}/>
    
   </Tab.Navigator> 
    
  );
}

 export default function App(){
   

    return (
      
      <NavigationContainer initialRouteName="Signin">
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Signin" component={Signin} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Forgotpass" component={Forgotpass}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Reset" component={Reset}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabnav} options={{headerLeft:()=>null, gestureEnabled: false,}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Dermatologistas" component={Dermatologistas}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Hospitais" component={Hospitais}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Cardiologista" component={Cardiologista}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Pneumologista" component={Pneumologista}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Odontologo" component={Odontologo}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Oftalmologista" component={Oftalmologista}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="UserProfile" component={userProfile}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/>
         
          <Stack.Screen name="Edit" component={Edit}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
       
      </NavigationContainer>
          
     );
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just needed to define a const in the stylesheet :)

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to import StyleSheet from react-native

```
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from "react-native";
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I actually already did it , just needed to remove from the question because stackoveflow said it had too much code

Answer (score 1):

you have for got the const keyword.
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

you have forgot to `import  StyleSheet` so this may be another Problem.

if the StyleSheet is declare in separate file you must have to export it like this

```
export default styles or export {styles}
```

to use styles in the other files . if you do `export default styles` like this  then import like this

`import styles from "../your/directroy/to/styles/"`

if you export like this

`export {styles}`

then import like this

`import {styles} from "../your/directroy/to/styles/"`

Comment: Thank you mate, but I that wasn't exactly the problem, I already imported everything and the bug problem is that it doesn't get applied in expo, but when I hit ctrl+s it updates like I changed something (what I didn't) but if I hit ctrl+S again in other screen the style gets lost